# Check if all values in a map are null

Tags: java, dictionary

I need to check if all values in a map are null, I have this method that I want to replace by a built-in one if possible. Limitations: Java 5 and access to Apache Commons libraries.

```
/* Checks if all values are null */
public static boolean isEmpty(Map<Dboid,?> aMap){

    boolean isEmpty = true;

    Iterator<?> it = aMap.entrySet().iterator();

    while(it.hasNext() && isEmpty){
        Object value = it.next();
        if(value != null) {
            isEmpty = false;
        }
    }

    return isEmpty;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by *native* here?

Comment: i guess OP native mean his own method

Comment: He meant "built-in", e.g. part of the Map API, or some other one-liner.

Comment: This shouldn't be named `isEmpty`, because there are keys, but the attached values might be `null`.

Comment: and you should break as soon as you find a non null value..

Comment: @MajidL He does. See `isEmpty` condition in loop.

Comment: Iterating through `entrySet()` is always going to return `Map.Entry` objects, never null, even if the key or the value in the map entry happens to be null.

Comment: @David you're right, there's a bug in my code

Comment: @JasonC no he doesn't

Comment: @MajidL Er... he does. When `value != null`, `isEmpty` is set to `false`, and the loop does not continue (`while (... && isEmpty)`). No further tests are performed once a non-`null` value is found.

Comment: @JasonC hmm you're right didn't see the isEmpty condition..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As such there is no direct method for this, but you can use [Apache Commons `CollectionUtils.countMatches()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#countMatches%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29) method, and pass a [`NullPredicate`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/functors/NullPredicate.html) instance to it. Of course, you would do pass the values in the map using `Map#values()` method:

```
public static <K, V> boolean hasAllNullValues(Map<K, V> map) {
    int size = map.size();
    return CollectionUtils.countMatches(map.values(), NullPredicate.INSTANCE) == size;
}
```

or even better, use [`CollectionUtils.exists()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#exists%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29) method, to check there is at least one element that satisfies the `NotNullPredicate` passed as second argument:

```
public static <K, V> boolean hasAllNullValues(Map<K, V> map) {
    return !CollectionUtils.exists(map.values(), NotNullPredicate.INSTANCE);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I know the question is for Java 5, but for those who will come here from google search as I did:

For Java >= 8 you can do:

```
boolean allValuesAreNull = yourMap.values()
        .stream()
        .allMatch(Objects::isNull);
```

with one nuance: it will be `true` for empty map.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution without using any third party libraries.

```
Collections.frequency(aMap.values(), null) == aMap.size()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in method to do this. In particular, there's nothing that provides a means of "finding an element that *isn't* equal to something".

However, if a map that contains only `null` values is defined by your business rules to be "empty", that seems to imply that `null` values mean "not present", in which case you may wish to construct the code such that `null` values are never added in the first place. Then you can just use the built in `isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
return CollectionUtils.find(aMap.values(),NotNullPredicate.INSTANCE).isEmpty();
```

Comment: Looks equivalent to Rohit's answer.

Comment: Yeah but this is better 
return !CollectionUtils.exists(map.values(), NotNullPredicate.INSTANCE);

Answer (score 1):

There is no API that will give you that, however you could optimize that method a little bit.

No need to check the isEmpty variable on every iteration.
That is a minor optimization.

```
/* Checks if all values are null */
public static <K,V> boolean isMapEmpty(Map<K,V> aMap){
    for (V v: aMap.values()) {
      if (v != null) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Jason typpo - got to be aMap.values(); The optimization is that he doesn't need an extra variable and extra check on each iteration .. that adds up.

Comment: hey what the downvote for? just want to help the guy

Comment: Most likely, it doesn't add up, and has zero effect. Please provide benchmarks and profile data to back up the claim, as well as a comparison against the OP's actual performance requirements, before suggesting premature micro-optimizations as a valid approach. Encouraging that thought process hurts more than helps and is exactly why we have so many bad "performance" related questions to fend off here.

Comment: I agree - its a micro-optimization and cleaning of the code. And that is all I offered... Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: @Deian check the isEmpty flag in the while loop.

Comment: @LluisMartinez - yes your code has that but you don't really need it. As soon as you see non null value you can leave on the spot.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes I follow the single return at the end of the method technique. Not always though :-)